# How can I cycle the values of 4 variables in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, integer

I have 4 integer variables: A,B,C & D.

I want to have a function called cycle() in which the value of A goes to B, the value of B goes to C, the value of C goes to D and the value of D goes to A.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 9):

ES6 lets you do this with [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
[a, b, c, d] = [b, c, d, a];
```

(`[d, a, b, c]` if “D goes to A” means A should get D’s value)

Answer (score 2):

you can use `push` and `shift` to do that. It will support N number of element to rotate.

```js
function cycle(arr){
        arr.push(arr.shift());
        // if you want d goes to a then 
        //arr.unshift(arr.pop());
        return arr;
    }
    
    var a = 1, b= 2, c = 3, d = 4;
    [a,b,c,d] = cycle([a,b,c,d]);
 console.log(a,b,c,d);
```